# Is there any option to DataSet / DataTable while accessing data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any option to DataSet / DataTable while accessing data from database fromm sql, oracle, mysql. data get it inro the json or xml. without using dataset or datatable.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It's quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executexmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private static void CreateXMLReader(string queryString,
    string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        System.Xml.XmlReader reader = command.ExecuteXmlReader();
    }
}
```

**JSON:**

```
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);    

using (JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw)) 
{    
    jsonWriter.WriteStartArray();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();

        int fields = rdr.FieldCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < fields; i++)
        { 
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(rdr.GetName(i));
            jsonWriter.WriteValue(rdr[i]);
        }

        jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
    }

    jsonWriter.WriteEndArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But other than xml is their any other solution.